# How does data.table define "nearest" in a rolling join?

Tags: r, data.table

The `data.table` [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/data.table/html/data.table.html) states `roll = "nearest"` means:

> When i is a data.table and its row matches to all but the last x join column, and its value in the last i join column falls in a gap (including after the last observation in x for that group), then... "nearest" rolls the nearest value

The `rollends` parameter states:

> If rollends[1]=TRUE, it will roll the first value backward. If rollends[2]=TRUE, it will roll the last value forward.

However, although `rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)` is the default for `roll = "nearest"`, when the row to join is before the first observation, the output is not as I expect.

### Minimal reproducible example

#### Sample data

`d` is a `data.table`, with two rows, which each contain an `id` and an `IDate`. `lookup` is a `data.table` with a `value` recorded for each `id` on a specific date. The date in `d` for `id` 1 is after the last recorded date for that `id` in `lookup`. The date in `d` for `id` 2 is before the first recorded date for that `id` in `lookup`.

```r
library(data.table)
lookup <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    date = seq(from = as.IDate("2020-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 6),
    value = c(1:6)
)

d <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2),
    date = as.IDate(c("2020-01-10", "2020-01-01"))
)

d

#       id       date
#    <num>     <IDat>
# 1:     1 2020-01-10
# 2:     2 2020-01-01

lookup

#       id       date value
#    <num>     <IDat> <int>
# 1:     1 2020-01-01     1
# 2:     1 2020-01-02     2
# 3:     1 2020-01-03     3
# 4:     2 2020-01-04     4
# 5:     2 2020-01-05     5
# 6:     2 2020-01-06     6
```

#### Join operation

I wish to join each `id` in `d` to the `value` on the nearest recorded date in `lookup`:

```r
d[lookup,
    on = c("id", "date"),
    roll = "nearest",
    value := i.value,
    rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)
]
```

#### Expected output

`id` 1 has the date `"2020-01-10"`, which is after all the dates for `id` 1 in lookup, so I expect it to the `value` on the final date, i.e. `3`. Similarly, `id` 2 has the date `"2020-01-01"`, which is before all the dates for `id` 2 in lookup, so I expect it to match to the `value` on the *first* date.

```r
      id       date value
   <num>     <IDat> <int>
1:     1 2020-01-10     3
2:     2 2020-01-01     4
```

#### Actual output

`id` 1 matches as expected. However, `id` 2 matches to the `value` 6, which is recorded on `"2020-01-06"`, i.e. the *final* date for group 2, rather than the first date. My understanding of "nearest" is that of the dates `c("2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06")`, the nearest to to `"2020-01-01"` is `"2020-01-04"`.

```r
      id       date value
   <num>     <IDat> <int>
1:     1 2020-01-10     3
2:     2 2020-01-01     6
```

This is the output regardless of whether `rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)` or any of the other three possible options.

### Session info

```r
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
packageVersion("data.table") #'1.14.7'
```

### Related questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274928/r-data-table-rolling-join-not-matching-nearest-value) is related but does not have an answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891231/r-data-table-rolling-join-confusion) has an answer which suggests doing the join the other way around, i.e.:

```r
lookup[d,
    on = c("id", "date"),
    roll = "nearest",
    nearest_date := i.date
]

d[lookup,
    on = c("id", "date" = "nearest_date"),
    value := i.value
]
```

This works, but it is two joins, which is more expensive, and more joins make code harder to maintain. In any case the fact that it works confirms I do not understand what "nearest" means.

Why does "nearest" act as expected if joining in one direction, but not the other? What is the definition of "nearest"? Is there a way to get the expected output with only one join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nearest` works as expected, but the inner table should be `d`.

What happens here is that `:=` is applied to all `lookup` values so that you get in `d` the last lookup value for each group : `3` and `6`

```
d[lookup,
  on = c("id", "date"),
  roll = "nearest",
  .(i.value,i.date,x.date)
]
   i.value     i.date     x.date
     <int>     <IDat>     <IDat>
1:       1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10
2:       2 2020-01-02 2020-01-10
3:       3 2020-01-03 2020-01-10 # Last value overwrites previous ones for id=1
4:       4 2020-01-04 2020-01-01
5:       5 2020-01-05 2020-01-01
6:       6 2020-01-06 2020-01-01 # Last value overwrites previous ones for id=2
```

Try :

```
lookup[d,
  on = c("id", "date"),
  roll = "nearest",
  .(id,i.date,x.value)
][]

      id     i.date x.value
   <num>     <IDat>   <int>
1:     1 2020-01-10       3
2:     2 2020-01-01       4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's helpful that it's because of values being overwritten. But I find it baffling that each value matches. The way I think about joins (and maybe this is a problem) is that you find the matching row(s) in the table on the right of `[`, and add the value in the columns defined in `:=` to a new column in the table on the left of `[`. Here they all seem to match - but why? Could you elaborate a little on _why_ this is expected behaviour - i.e. what does "nearest" mean if all the rows are nearest?

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the mix between the join and `:=`. If you look at the join without `:=` (first part of my answer, corrected a typo), you see that the `nearest` worked exactly as expected, for each row in `lookup` it finds the nearest date in `d`. Now when you use `:=`, as you have 3 matches for each row of  `d`, `:=` is applied 3 times and you see only the last `:=`